# Error after "from new import instancemethod" when importing scipy.stats

Tags: python, scipy, python-2.x

I am getting an exception from `scipy` whenever I try to import the `nltk` package. The command and the error looks like this:

```
>>> import nltk
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/nltk/__init__.py", line 114, in <module>
from nltk.collocations import *
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/nltk/collocations.py", line       39, in <module>
from nltk.metrics import ContingencyMeasures, BigramAssocMeasures, TrigramAssocMeasures
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/nltk/metrics/__init__.py", line 16, in <module>
from nltk.metrics.scores import          (accuracy, precision, recall, f_measure,
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/nltk/metrics/scores.py", line 16, in <module>
from scipy.stats.stats import betai
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scipy/stats/__init__.py", line 344, in <module>
from .stats import *
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scipy/stats/stats.py", line 176, in <module>
from . import distributions
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scipy/stats/distributions.py", line 10, in <module>
 from ._distn_infrastructure import (entropy, rv_discrete, rv_continuous,
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scipy/stats/_distn_infrastructure.py", line 43, in <module>
 from new import instancemethod
File "new.py", line 107
return copy.deepcopy(self)
^
IndentationError: expected an indented block
```

I executed this command in a terminal (ubuntu 16.04 LTS system). I did not find anything about this error and the indentation doesn't look wrong.

Comment: python is telling you, you need to indent the code properly!

Comment: I know that @ΦXocę웃Пepeúpaツ but the question is I just inserted an importing code which I don't think had any indentation problem .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The SyntaxError is in **your** file `new.py` (I guess it's in your current working directory). Try to switch to a directory where no `new.py` file is present (or move the `new.py` file in another directory), then the internal scipy import should work without problems.

On the other hand you can just upgrade to scipy 0.19.x. They removed the import there and it should work without problems.

---

Note that it's always a bad idea to name python files like [builtin-modules](https://docs.python.org/2/library/new.html)! That's a common source for exceptions or unexpected behaviour.

Comment: Thanks for answer @MSeifert . I have moved new.py file to another folder and now code is working fine . Thank u so much again .